# The word "examples" with third person singular verb?

Tags: third-person-singular

> Listen to a few example**s** which **uses** this letter.

I found this sentence while I was reading, I wondered why the third person singular verb was used here and thought it was a wrong spelling.

Then I googled "examples which..." and I found some more instances like:

> Tell any three example**s** which **shows** UX design is future need?
>   Topology example**s** which **fits** to the ZV4002 restrictions

Comment: All are simply wrong. 'Tell any three' is also a good indicator the writer wasn't native English.

Comment: Be careful when searching for examples online. Just because it's written in English doesn't mean it was written by a competent, fluent, or native English speaker. Try to take examples from reputable sources, like well-known newspapers, books, and dictionaries.

Comment: However, there are cases when the word **examples** may be followed by a singular verb, such as: **They selected only positive examples which shows that they were prejudiced.**.However, it's *the selection* rather than the examples themselves that takes the singular verb.

Comment: @Ronald Sole It's a little tricky for me to understand. _The selection_ as a whole idea is kind of hard to recognize. Since _which_ is immediately after _examlpes_, it's confusing.

Comment: @preachers If you break the sentence into two, it's easier to understand: **They selected only positive examples. This shows that they were prejudiced.** It's clear that **this** refers to the selection of positive examples. The same is true if you link the two sentences with **which**. It's like saying:**She is kind to dogs which shows that she is a good person**.

Comment: @Ronald Sole Oh, I see. It's more of a semantical rather than a grammatical thing. Much more clear now, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Ronald Sole brings up a valid case, where there can be an *implied* singular subject that validates the conjugation.  It is possible to imagine the words missing from your example sentences:

> Listen to a few examples **(from a passage)** which uses this letter.
>
> Tell (us) any three examples **(any one of)** which shows UX design is (a) future need?
>
> Topology examples **(of a specification)** which fits to the ZV4002 restrictions

Still, as written all three are awkward and not idiomatic.  There is no reason to assume a secondary subject.  It's more likely these are either grammatical mistakes, or they were written by non-native speakers.

In each, the singular conjugation makes more sense:

> Listen to a few examples which **use** this letter.
>
> Tell (us) any three examples which **show** UX design is (a) future need?
>
> Topology examples which **fit** the ZV4002 restrictions.